# What's the difference between the euclidean algorithm and the extended euclidean algorithm?

Tags: number-theory

What does the euclidean algorithm compute, and what problems is the extended euclidean algorithm used for? Can someone please show how they each differ on the pair $(210,65)$

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are lots of pages written about that, yet I'll try explain it in the simplest way. Given two integers $a$ and $b$:

- the *Euclidean Algorithm* computes $GCD(a,b)$
- the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm* gives out *2* integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=GCD(a,b)$; mainly used when $GCD(a,b) = 1$

There is a [page](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math418/m418oh/m418oh04.pdf) giving a clear example of the differences between the *Algorithms*. In your case $(a=210,b=65)$ aplying the *Euclidean Algorithm*:
\begin{cases}
210 = 65\cdot 3+15\\
65 = 15\cdot 4 +5\\
15 = 5\cdot 3 \Rightarrow GCD(210,65) = 5
\end{cases}

Instead, if we wish to find *2* integers $x$ and $y$ such that $210x+65y=GCD(210,65)=5$, we use the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*:

\begin{cases}
5 = 65-15\cdot4\\
5 = 65-(210-65\cdot 3)\cdot4\\
5= 210\cdot -4 + 65\cdot 13 \Rightarrow (x,y) = (-4,13)
\end{cases}
The couple $(x,y)$ is also called *pair of [Bézout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) coefficients*, and as you can imagine a pair can be found by using the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*, but there are infinite couples $(x,y)$ which satisfy the equation $ax+by=GCD(a,b)$.