# Solving Linear Congruences with Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, euclidean-algorithm

I have the following equation: $70x \equiv 2 \pmod {58}$ and this equation: $X = X_i + i \times \frac{n}{d}$.

Using the table method with Euclidean algorithm I do $6$ steps to find out $\rm{gcd}(70,58) = d = 2\quad\quad$ I know that $n = 58$ however what are $X_i$ & $i$.

How do I solve this equation ?

I assumed $X_i$ was denominator at step $i$ and $i$ was the number of step where the Euclidean algorithm ended. Seems I am wrong.

Comment: It's even easier to write in mathjax than in whatever you were writing in, just `$X_i$` instead of X[sub]i[/sub] or whatever you were using :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_i$ is any solution to the linear congruence $70x≡2 (\mod 58)$, $n$ is 58 as you mentioned and $i$ is any integer.

Therefore, what the equation really means is that from any particular solution $X_i$, we can construct an infinite amount of solutions $X = X_i + \frac{i*n}{d}$, where $d = \gcd(a,m)$.

You can find that particular solution $X_i$ either by inspection (if there is a trivial or obvious value of x that would make the equation hold) or by the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

If you haven't seen the EEA, this post might help: [What's the difference between the euclidean algorithm and the extended euclidean algorithm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718016/whats-the-difference-between-the-euclidean-algorithm-and-the-extended-euclidean)